# Excel VBA User Form option buttons

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I've created a userform that will require an option button to be selected (thus emailing the intended recipient), otherwise it will display a `msgbox`.

I'm having a problem with the `If` `And` `Then` `Else` statements. I need the code to continue if one of the option buttons is selected, only display the `msgbox` if there are no option buttons selected.

I'm sure this is a newbie error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub cmdSend_Click()

If optbeasley.Value = False _
And optmaney.Value = False _
And optmessana.Value = False _
And opttimmerman.Value = False _
And opttrotter.Value = False _
Then MsgBox "Please Select a Contact"
Else:

Next i
Call Important_relocate_reformat

    If Me.optbeasley.Value = True Then
    Call Module4.Email_beasley
    Unload Me
    End If
        If Me.optmaney.Value = True Then
        Call Module4.Email_maney
        Unload Me
        End If
            If Me.optmessana.Value = True Then
            Call Module4.Email_messana
            Unload Me
            End If
                If Me.opttimmerman.Value = True Then
                Call Module4.Email_timmerman
                Unload Me
                End If
                    If Me.opttrotter.Value = True Then
                    Call Module4.Email_trotter
                    Unload Me
                    End If
                        If Me.chkMattBeasley.Value = True Then
                        Call Email_beasley
                        End If
If Me.chkRickLeshane.Value = True Then
Call Email_Important_Leshane
End If
        If Me.chkTimRuppert.Value = True Then
        Call Email_Important_Ruppert
        End If



End Sub
Private Sub optbeasley_Click()
If optbeasley.Value = True Then
        chkMattBeasley.Enabled = False
    Else
        chkMattBeasley.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub optmaney_Click()
Call optbeasley_Click
End Sub
Private Sub opttimmerman_Click()
Call optbeasley_Click
End Sub
Private Sub opttrotter_Click()
Call optbeasley_Click
End Sub
Private Sub optmessana_Click()
Call optbeasley_Click
End Sub
```

I've edited to show the usage of your code:

```
Private Sub cmdSend_Click()

If optbeasley = 0 And optmaney = 0 And optmessana = 0 And opttimmerman = 0 And opttrotter = 0 Then
MsgBox "Please Select a Contact"
Else: Call cmdSend_Click2
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you missing an extra `End If` at the end of your sub `cmdSend_Click`?

Comment: I tried adding <code>End If</code> but it throws back an error IF End If without IF block I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the formatting, apparently. This works -

```
Sub example()
Dim optbeasley As Range
Dim optmaney As Range
Dim optmessana As Range
Dim opttimmerman As Range
Dim optrotter As Range

Set optbeasley = Range("A1")
Set optmaney = Range("A2")
Set optmessana = Range("A3")
Set opttimmerman = Range("A4")
Set optrotter = Range("A5")

If optbeasley = False _
And optmaney = False _
And optmessana = False _
And opttimmerman = False _
And opttrotter = False Then
MsgBox "Please Select a Contact"
Else: MsgBox ("hi")
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I need to check if no option buttons are selected. 
If one is selected, then I need to run the rest of the code. If the code detects that none of the option buttons are true, then the message box will appear and re-run the macro to check again.
But if I run <code>ElseIf</code> won't it show the message box each time because one of the option buttons will not be selected, since only one can be selected at a time.

Comment: @Joe updated again

Comment: This works fantastically! I appreciate your help. Since the Option Buttons (radio buttons) are not defined by cells on a spreadsheed (userform) I adapted to recognize them as option buttons.

Thank you all for your time and help!

Comment: @Joe excellent, sorry I got pretty confused on the troubleshooting, hence all the edits. Glad it worked out finally